# JSON extraction

Tags: java, json, role-playing-game

Given the code below, is there a better way to essentially create different native objects without changing the native constructor or the nativeList.json file? The only option I can see is adding a `String nativeType` variable to the constructor and creating the native object based on that the type passed. So to create all the types of natives I would create an array and just loop through that, each time passing the same native name and a different type.

I would like to avoid this because I believe there are like 20 - 25 different types, so I was wondering if you had any suggestions.

**Entity.java**

```
package models;

public class Entity {

    private int xPos, yPos; // used to keep track of the entity's position on the board
    private String imgFilePath; // used to show image file for entity 
    private int entityNum; // used to uniquely identify a character
    private String entityName; // used for entity name

    /***** Getter Methods *****/
    // Get the entity's x position on the board
    public int getxPos() {
        return xPos;
    }

    // Get the entity's y position on the board
    public int getyPos() {
        return yPos;
    }

    // Get the entity's image
    public String getImgFilePath() {
        return imgFilePath;
    }

    // Get entity number
    public int getEntityNum() {
        return entityNum;
    }

    // Get the entity's name
    public String getEntityName() {
        return entityName;
    }

    /***** Setter Methods *****/
    // Set the entity's x position on the board
    public void setxPos(int xPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
    }

    // Set the entity's y position on the board
    public void setyPos(int yPos) {
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

    // Set the entity's image
    public void setImgFilePath(String imgFilePath) {
        this.imgFilePath = imgFilePath;
    }

    // Set the entity's unique identifying number
    public void setEntityNum(int entityNum) {
        this.entityNum = entityNum;
    }

    // Set the entity's name
    public void setEntityName(String entityName) {
        this.entityName = entityName;
    }

}
```

**Native.java**

```
package models;

import java.io.FileReader;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class Native extends Entity {

    private Weapon weapon;
    private long wage;
    private long[] bounty; // the first element of bounty is notoriety, second element is gold
    private String move[]; // move for native
    private String weight;
    private String[] vul; // vulnerability first element is vulnerability of native and second is armor of native
    private String[] readyStats; // First element of array letter, second is effort, third is fatigue, fourth is sharpness
    private String[] unReadyStats; // First element of array letter, second is effort, third is fatigue, fourth is sharpness
    private String group; // group that native is part of
    JSONParser parser;

    public Native(String nativeName){
        System.out.println(nativeName);
        // Take native name and parse native JSON. Used returned values to fill in details for native
        parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("res/nativeList.json"));

            for(Object o : array) {
                JSONObject currNative = (JSONObject) o;

                String n = (String) currNative.get("Name");

                if(n.equals(nativeName)) {
                    setImgFilePath((String) currNative.get("File Path")); // Set the image file for weapon
                    setEntityName((String) currNative.get("Name")); // Set the name for the entity
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /***** Getter Methods *****/
    // Return weapon native has
    public Weapon getWeapon() {
        return weapon;
    }

    // Return wage to hire native
    public long getWage() {
        return wage;
    }

    // Return bounty for native
    public long[] getBounty() {
        return bounty;
    }

    // Return move of native
    public String[] getMove() {
        return move;
    }

    // Return weight of native
    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    // Return vulnerability and armor of native
    public String[] getVul() {
        return vul;
    }

    // Return the ready statistics of native
    public String[] getReadyStats() {
        return readyStats;
    }

    // Return the un-ready statistics of native
    public String[] getUnreadyStats() {
        return unReadyStats;
    }

    // Return what group native is part of
    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    /***** Setter Methods *****/
    // Set the current native's inventory
    public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    // Set the wage to hire native
    public void setWage(long wage) {
        this.wage = wage;
    }

    // Set bounty for native
    public void setBounty(long[] bounty) {
        this.bounty = bounty;
    }

    // Set move strength for native
    public void setMove(String[] move) {
        this.move = move;
    }

    // Set the weight for the native
    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    // Set the vulnerability of the native
    public void setVul(String[] vul) {
        this.vul = vul;
    }

    // Set the ready statistics for the native
    public void setReadyStats(String[] readyStats){
        this.readyStats = readyStats;
    }

    // Set the un-ready statistics for the native
    public void setUnreadyStats(String[] unReadyStats) {
        this.unReadyStats = unReadyStats;
    }

    // Set the group native is in
    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    // Used for testing purposes
    public String toString() {
        String strToReturn = "Native Details\n";
        return strToReturn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Native n = new Native("Knight");
    }
}
```

**nativeList.json**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Knight",
        "Weapon": {
            "Length": 7,
            "Type": "Broadsword"
        },
        "VUL": {
            "Vulnerability": "Tremendous",
            "Armor": "Armored" 
        },
        "Wage": 8,
        "Bounty": {
            "Notoriety": 12,
            "Gold": 8
        },
        "Move": "Tremendous",
        "Weight": "Heavy",
        "Type": {
            "OHQ": {
                "Attack": {
                    "Unalerted": {
                        "letter": "H",
                        "effort": "6",
                        "fatigue": "1"
                    },
                    "Alerted": {
                        "letter": "T",
                        "effort": "4",
                        "fatigue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Move": {
                    "Unalerted": 4,
                    "Alerted": 6
                }
            },
            "O1": {
                "Attack": {
                    "Unalerted": {
                        "letter": "H",
                        "effort": "4",
                        "fatigue": "1"
                    },
                    "Alerted": {
                        "letter": "T",
                        "effort": "5",
                        "fatigue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Move": {
                    "Unalerted": 6,
                    "Alerted": 5
                }
            },
            "O2": {
                "Attack": {
                    "Unalerted": {
                        "letter": "H",
                        "effort": "5",
                        "fatigue": "1"
                    },
                    "Alerted": {
                        "letter": "T",
                        "effort": "5",
                        "fatigue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Move": {
                    "Unalerted": 5,
                    "Alerted": 6
                }
            },
            "O3": {
                "Attack": {
                    "Unalerted": {
                        "letter": "H",
                        "effort": "4",
                        "fatigue": "1"
                    },
                    "Alerted": {
                        "letter": "T",
                        "effort": "5",
                        "fatigue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Move": {
                    "Unalerted": 6,
                    "Alerted": 6
                }
            }
        },
        "Hiring Costs": {
            "Order": "Individual"
        },
        "File Path": "natives/knight.gif"
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve... Currently there's only a "Knight" in your `nativeList.json` and you parse that into a `Native` object. Are you asking how to parse the Knight into a `Knight extends Native` object and then perhaps another native named "Healer" into a `Healer extends Native` object? Or are you just troubled by the amount of parsing you would need to do with your current way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, parsing JSON files manually as `JSONObject` classes etc. is not very nice or productive. You need to use some *object mapper*. I can recommend Jackson for you, it's quite nice. See, for example, this example: http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial

Basically your parsing code would then boil down to this part of the tutorial:

```
//read json file data to String
byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("employee.txt"));

//create ObjectMapper instance
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

//convert json string to object
Employee emp = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Employee.class);

System.out.println("Employee Object\n"+emp);
```

Just replace "Employee" with "Native" etc...

Comment: Yes a object mapper is really the way to go. I'd recommend you to take a look at `Gson` (https://github.com/google/gson)  as well.